# React useEffect return argument without dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that if you pass an empty array `[]` as the second argument to React's `useEffect()` it will act like a `componentDidMount`, and if you don't pass anything it is more like a `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`. What about the return argument? I know it is supposed to be like `componentWillUnmount` in some ways, but what difference does it make in this case whether or not if you pass an empty array or no argument at all?

```
useEffect(() => {
  return myUnmountFunction
})
```

vs.

```
useEffect(() => {
  return myUnmountFunction
}, [])
```

Comment: The return function, if provided, is a cleanup function. It runs before the effect is run again. If you provide an empty dependency array it will run once when the component unmounts. If you provide no dependencies it runs on every subsequent render, because that’s when the effect itself is run.

Comment: empty array will clean up on unmount, without it will cleanup on every re-render